# How to get 5V power output from Raspberry pi Pico

Tags: pi-pico

After going through the Raspberry pi Pico datasheet it has only 3.3V power output. I want to power some devices that require 5V from the Pico.

How can I get 5V output from the Raspberry Pico?

Comment: Don't connect outputs from your 5 V devices to the Pi unless you are absolutely certain that the voltages will not exceed 3.3 V.

Comment: why would you use the Raspberry Pico as a power supply?

Answer (score 14):

You don't. It is a 3.3V device which CAN be powered by 5V (often USB).

If you have low power 5V devices you can power from the VBUS or VSYS pins which can be used for power if you run the Pico from 5V.

VBUS is the micro-USB input voltage, connected to micro-USB port pin 1. This is nominally 5 V (or 0 V if the USB is not connected or not powered).
VSYS is the main system input voltage, which can vary in the allowed range 1.8 V to 5.5 V, and which is used by the on-board SMPS (switch mode power supply) to generate the 3.3 V for the RP2040 and its GPIO.

The Pico Schematic is in Appendix B: [Raspberry Pi Pico Datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/pico/pico-datasheet.pdf)

Comment: Can you add to this answer if the VBUS/VSYS pins are connected directly to the power source or if there is protection in place? Very relevant if powering from USB.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you mean by saying:

> some devices that require 5V from the Pico

but if you mean other devices that shall work in the same project as your Pico I would suggest extra LM7805 IC (5V DC regulator) and use the output of it for both: Pico power supply as well as other devices. At least this is how I did for my projects. Although Pico can work with anything between 1.8 - 5.5V, it is always a good idea to have stable voltage for Pico as well.
The cost of LM7805 is below 1$, plus 2 small capacitors on IN and OUT and you are done