# Raspberry Pi Pico 5V output using VBUS?

Tags: power, pi-pico

there! I'm planning to use the Raspberry Pi Pico for a project and I'll be using a SCA60c tilt sensor with it. I know that the Pico only has a 3.3V output but the SCA60C needs 5V to power it. I was wondering if I can use the VBUS to power the SCA60C?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get 5V power output from Raspberry pi Pico](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/127864/how-to-get-5v-power-output-from-raspberry-pi-pico)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's what VBUS is for.

This assumes that there is spare current available for the SCA60c.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is much appreciated :D